# How to pass headers in Lambda Call from another Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, invoke

I need to call LambdaA from another LambdaB. But LambdaA has required user authentication.
How to pass the headers to LambdaA.
Here is the code to call the LambdaA fro LambdaB

```
async invoke(data = {}, invokeType = 'RequestResponse') {
        // call options
        const opts = {
            FunctionName: this._lambdaTarget,
            InvocationType: invokeType,
            Payload: JSON.stringify({ body: data })
        };

        // return promise
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // call function
            this._lambda.invoke(opts, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    // call failure
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    // call success
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "has required user authentication"? How was LambdaA invoked?

Comment: It means that LambdaA is an authorized API, means only logged in user can access the API.

Comment: How `_lambdaTarget ` function get header?

Comment: @hoangdv _lambdaTarget is the dynamic function name. I want to know that how to set the header to call the LambdaA

Comment: How is LambdaA being invoked? Is it being called via API Gateway, or directly via the `invoke()` API call, or some other way? Please edit your question to add full details.

Comment: Just call it without header and see the response.

Answer (score 0):

The question is similar to [How to add headers to aws-cli lambda invoke command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69762968/6344916). There the call is via CLI (AWS SDK inside). Here - via code that uses AWS SDK.

Please, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75618682/6344916).

Hope, it will help.