# How to add headers to aws-cli lambda invoke command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

As the title says, I can't seem to invoke lambda function with any headers. Please help, thanks.

```
aws lambda invoke --function function-name --payload "{\"some\": \"value\"}" outfile.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add headers"? Anything you provide in the `payload` will be provided to the AWS Lambda function via the `event` parameter. There is no concept of 'headers' in Lambda.

Comment: Do you have API Gateway in front of this Lambda? Are you trying to invoke the Lambda via API Gateway and want to add HTTP headers to the API request?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

As of 2023-03-02, there is **no way to add "headers" to an AWS Lambda call via the AWS SDK `lambda.invoke` function**. This function only has access to the called lambda payload.

### Additional information

**IF** you really need to pass something additional to the called lambda, then there are 2 ways.

1. Add the data as another field to your payload. Then process it in the receiving lambda code. This option can be used for `lambda.invoke` function (using lambda name) and HTTP-calls (using lambda URL or API Gateway). Just like @Harret did:

```
aws lambda invoke --function function-name <your-Lambda-name> /
-- payload '{ "headers": {"header1": "headerOneContent"} , "body": {...} }' outfile.txt
```

2. Create a corresponding API Gateway endpoint as a proxy for your lambda. Or create `Function URL` for it. Then GET/POST/... to this URL. Then lambda event will have headers:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  ...
  const headerOneContent = event.headers["header1"];
  ...
};
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/

Answer (score 1):

When invoking a lamda function via the AWS CLI, the payload has a specific structure which can include header information.

This can be done by adding a "headers" property to the root of the payload JSON object, which is intepreted and injected into the HTTP headers in the request sent to the lambda.

When a lambda function method, such as in C#, accepts `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` as an argument (see the Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents NuGet package), the headers passed in the JSON via the CLI can be extracted from its `Headers` property. Note, however, that the payload needs to be base-64 encoded, and not plain JSON.

Sample JSON

```json
{"headers": {"SomeValue": "ynmyttmRyLdhAnlp9A"}}
```

Powershell commands

```
#Get the base-64 encoded value
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('{"headers": {"SomeValue": "ynmyttmRyLdhAnlp9A"}}'))

#invoke the function and write the result to a LambdaResult.json file
aws lambda invoke --function-name some-lambda --profile "default" --payload 'eyJoZWFkZXJzIjogeyJTb21lVmFsdWUiOiAieW5teXR0bVJ5TGRoQW5scDlBIn19' "C:\Temp\LambdaResult.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

`aws lambda invoke --function function-name <your-Lambda-name> -- payload '{ "headers": {"some": "value"} }' outfile.txt`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain it.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The example just adds a "header" field to the lambda's payload. So there are no web request properties, including headers.